# netbeans 7.3 build host c/cpp

Tags: c++, c, netbeans, build, host

I am new to Netbeans and I have just installed Netbeans 7.3 with full features. I tried running c/c++ projects and it seems that I have a problem with this "Build Host" thing. I tried adding my institute's proxy address while trying to add a new remote host but it says it cannot connect to the given address. Is it really necessary to provide a remote host to run a c/c++ project. Or else please suggest me a solution to overcome this problem. And if possible please explain about this build host and stuffs. I'll be very grateful to you.

Answer (score 0):

there is no IDE work on my computer just devc++ and turboc and the two is too bad i want vc++ express or netBean c++  but nothing work ! i don't know why but i hate this situation it's too bad !:(